# Raid two external hard-drives with read/write support on Windows & OS X

Tags: macos, hard-drive, windows, external-disk, raid

I have a USB 3 HDD enclosure that currently has two 1TB drives in it. I am looking at buying another external USB 3 HDD drive (not an enclosure). I am currently running the external enclosure with the drives formatted as HSF+. I am wanting to set up a 2nd external drive using exFat and raid them.

I am assuming to merge the two external drives into a RAID configuration I will need some sort of software RAID. Is there any cross-platform software raid packages I can install on Windows 7/8 and OS X so that I can access the data across both platforms? I dual boot my MacBook with Windows and it is really a pain that each time I need a file from my external drive, I have to reboot into OS X, copy it to my Windows partition then reboot back in to Windows.

If this is not achievable with multiple external HDD's, can you recommend a set up that I could use that would provide multi-platform RAID support? Would this be achievable only with a single external enclosure using hardware RAID?

Thanks for the help!